# Trabajar con diferentes pestañas, del Notebook tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo una duda o problema, quizás haya respuesta, pero no consigo entender aún.

Tengo una aplicación, que trabaja con varias pestañas de Notebook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en cualquier botón, me llama a una función que a su ves trabaja con una clase donde me crea, la pestaña y los widgets:

```
def abrir_issuesDesviacion(self):
        global desviacion
        desviacion = Desviacion(self.root)
        self.cuaderno.add(desviacion, text='Issues DESVIACIONES')
        self.cuaderno.select(desviacion)
        desviacion.DESVfr1_entModulo.focus()
```

Hasta hay genial, hago mis tareas puedo abrir,.pestañas y trabajar en ellas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que en la barra de menú o en menú contextual del click derecho, al darle a buscar, llamar a una función sencilla que hace:

```
def buscar(self, event):
        self.DESVfr1_entModulo.focus()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es activar el foco en el entry, al abrir cada pestaña y lograr hacer CTRL+F, o buscar en el menú, me logra activar el foco, el problema es cuando vuelvo a una pestaña anterior, ya no me funciona esto, y he visto que es porque quizás en cada pestaña, se crear con un nombre diferente al widget:

#### Pestaña 1

```
.!desviacion.!labelframe.!entry
```

#### Pestaña 2

```
.!desviacion2.!labelframe.!entry
```

Creo entender que siempre está activa la última pestaña.

He visto que se habla mucho de las etiquetas de enlaces, y creo que puede ser la solución pero no entiendo cómo puedo implementar en mi caso.

Gracias